# Retrieve data corresponding to last day of every month sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Input:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2023 | 45 |
| 02-01-2023 | 282 |
| ........ | ...... |
| 31-01-2023 | 887 |

Output:

| header 1 | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 31-01-2023 | 887 |

These are daily data recorded across multiple months, where I want to retrieve the last day of each month in sql

Aim is to retrieve data corresponding to last day of every month sql

Retrieve data corresponding to last day of every month sql

Comment: What exactly is the "last day of every month"? The last day of the month in the calendar or the last day in your table? So, if you don't have a row for 2023-01-31, but one for 2023-01-30, do you want to show the 2023-01-30 row or none? Or will there be an entry for every day of each month anyway?

Comment: yes last day of table and not month, thanks

Comment: Okay. That was unclear. You should update your request with this information, so future readers with the same problem understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sure @ThorstenKettner , I've added an extended question here now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77275236/tag-pass-or-fail-based-on-condition-sql, appreciate if you can look into it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT LAST_DAY(TRUNC(date_column, 'MM'))   AS last_day_of_month,
       MAX(date_column)                     AS last_day_of_month_in_table,
       SUM(value)                           AS total_for_entire_month,
       SUM(value) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY TRUNC(date_column)
       )                                    AS total_for_last_day_in_table_of_month,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN TRUNC(date_column) = LAST_DAY(TRUNC(date_column))
         THEN value
         END
       )                                    AS total_for_only_last_day_of_month
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY TRUNC(date_column, 'MM')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_column, value) AS
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-01',   45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-02',  282 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-31',  887 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-02-01',    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-02-20',    2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH | LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH_IN_TABLE | TOTAL_FOR_ENTIRE_MONTH | TOTAL_FOR_LAST_DAY_IN_TABLE_OF_MONTH | TOTAL_FOR_ONLY_LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-31 00:00:00 | 2023-01-31 00:00:00 | 1214 | 887 | 887 |
| 2023-02-28 00:00:00 | 2023-02-20 00:00:00 | 3 | 2 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6NFzjpvW)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [LAST_DAY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/functions062.htm) function for this :

```
SELECT date,
       value
FROM table
WHERE date = LAST_DAY(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`LAST_DAY(date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions072.htm) function that will return a Date object with the last day of the month you provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX OVER` to get the last date for a month in the table. Then only select rows the dates of which match the months' last dates.

```
select date, value
from
(
  select
    date,
    value,
    max(date) over (partition by trunc(date, 'mm')) as last_date
  from mytable
)
where date = last_date
order by date;
```

Or do it the old fashioned way:

```
select *
from mytable
where date in 
(
  select max(date)
  from mytable
  group by trunc(date, 'mm')
)
order by date;
```