# Tag pass or fail based on condition SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Input:

table1

| id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | stud |
| 2 | stud |
| 3 | stud |

table2

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-09-2023 |
| 1 | 29-09-2023 |
| 2 | 29-09-2023 |
| 2 | 28-09-2023 |
| 3 | 15-08-2023 |

Output

| id | date | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-09-2023 | pass |
| 2 | 29-09-2023 | pass |
| 3 | 15-08-2023 | fail |

Aim here is to create the output table based on 2 input table, logic here is that I'm trying to fetch the last record of each month for each id which gives the id & date column respectively, since id 2 does not have last day of month which is 30th Sep, I pick the last day available in the given data.

Next 'result' column is framed as 'pass' if an 'id' has an entry in the past 10 days, else the result of the student is fail, for example, id 3 does not have a date entry in the past 10 days, so result is fail, while other two id's result is pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       t2.date_column,
       CASE
       WHEN t2.date_column >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '10' DAY
       THEN 'pass'
       ELSE 'fail'
       END AS result
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT id,
                date_column,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY id, TRUNC(date_column, 'MM')
                  ORDER BY date_column DESC
                ) AS rn
         FROM   table2
       ) t2
       ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t2.rn = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (id) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (id, date_column) AS
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) -  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 52 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | DATE_COLUMN | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-03 00:00:00 | pass |
| 2 | 2023-10-02 00:00:00 | pass |
| 3 | 2023-08-21 00:00:00 | fail |
| 3 | 2023-09-22 00:00:00 | fail |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eeNDv3c_)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the 1st table is irrelevant as you don't select anything from it. If you do need it (because not all IDs have matching row in the 2nd table), use it with outer join to the 2nd table.

As of desired result, today is 11th of October 2023, so no rows *pass* as it's been more than 10 days from all dates involved. That's why I set limit to 15 days (line #10).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with t2 (id, datum) as
  2    (select 1, date '2023-09-30' from dual union all
  3     select 1, date '2023-09-29' from dual union all
  4     select 2, date '2023-09-29' from dual union all
  5     select 2, date '2023-09-28' from dual union all
  6     select 3, date '2023-08-15' from dual
  7    )
```

Query:

```
  8  select id,
  9    max(datum) datum,
 10    case when trunc(sysdate) - max(datum) <= 15 then 'pass'
 11         else 'fail'
 12    end as result
 13  from t2
 14  group by id;

        ID DATUM      RESULT
---------- ---------- -------
         1 30-09-2023 pass
         2 29-09-2023 pass
         3 15-08-2023 fail

SQL>
```

---

If there are other columns involved (seems so, according to comments you posted, but no effort in modifying sample data), then one option is to use analytic function (such as `row_number` or `rank`), *sort* rows per ID and month by datum in descending order, and then fetch rows that ranked as the highest.

Something like this:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     t2 (id, datum, col)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 1, DATE '2023-09-30', 'A' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 1, DATE '2023-09-29', 'B' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 1, DATE '2023-08-15', 'C' FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-13', 'D' FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-08', 'E' FROM DUAL
 13         UNION ALL
 14         SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-02', 'F' FROM DUAL
 15         UNION ALL
 16         SELECT 2, DATE '2023-09-29', 'A' FROM DUAL
 17         UNION ALL
 18         SELECT 2, DATE '2023-09-28', 'B' FROM DUAL
 19         UNION ALL
 20         SELECT 3, DATE '2023-08-15', 'A' FROM DUAL),
```

Query:

```
 21     temp
 22     AS
 23        (SELECT id,
 24                datum,
 25                col,
 26                ROW_NUMBER ()
 27                   OVER (PARTITION BY id, TO_CHAR (datum, 'yyyymm') ORDER BY datum DESC) rn
 28           FROM t2)
 29    SELECT id, datum, col
 30      FROM temp
 31     WHERE rn = 1
 32  ORDER BY id, datum DESC;

        ID DATUM      C
---------- ---------- -
         1 30-09-2023 A
         1 15-08-2023 C
         1 13-06-2023 D
         2 29-09-2023 A
         3 15-08-2023 A

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot, this would select only 1 max date for each id, but not last record of each month, do you have a way out for that ?

Comment: There's no difference - not with sample data you posted.

Comment: with sample data there is no difference, but in original data the scenario required is to pick max date in each month (not just overall) as mentioned in the post, thanks

Comment: Aha; so, you are basically saying that we (the community) should **guess** what original table looks like and write code based on it? Sorry, but that's not the way it goes. Put some effort and edit the original question you posted, provide sample data that illustrates the problem and **then** you'll get a *better* answer. Because, the way it is now, code I posted does exactly what you asked.

Comment: Please read the question again @Littlefoot, It is already mentioned in the question - "logic here is that I'm trying to fetch the last record of each month for each id"

Comment: Please read the question again @Littlefoot, It is already mentioned in the question - "logic here is that I'm trying to fetch the last record of each month for each id" (here last record of each month means there are many months in the given data, while the code you posted will give only for last month not each month), please don't assume that I'm expecting community to guess which is not right, if you have a way out for each month then pls post the updated solution else not a problem, thanks again.

Comment: Edited, the way I understood what you are saying.