# Conditional pass fail column sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Input:

table1

| id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | stud |
| 2 | stud |
| 3 | stud |

table2

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-09-2023 |
| 1 | 29-09-2023 |
| 2 | 29-09-2023 |
| 2 | 28-09-2023 |
| 3 | 15-08-2023 |

table3:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-09-2023 |
| 1 | 29-09-2023 |
| 1 | 29-08-2023 |
| 2 | 28-09-2023 |
| 3 | 17-07-2023 |

Output

| id | date | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-09-2023 | pass |
| 1 | 29-08-2023 | pass |
| 2 | 29-09-2023 | pass |
| 3 | 15-08-2023 | fail |

Aim: To create the output table based on 3 input table,
logic is to fetch the last record for each month for each id which gives the id & date (date column is to be extracted from table 2 and not table 3) respectively, since id 2 does not have last day of month which is 30th Sep, I pick the last day available in the given data.

'result' column is framed as 'pass' if an 'id' has a date entry in the past 20 days either in table 2 or in table 3, else the result of the student is fail, for example, id 3 does not have a date entry in the past 20 days in both table 2 & table 3, so result is fail, while other two id's result is pass

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice. If your first question is not clear then improve that question. If this is not the same as the previous question then you need to make explicitly clear what the difference between the two questions is (because, other than changing 10 days to 20 days, I am not seeing an obvious difference).

Comment: Please [edit] the question and explain what you have tried (include **YOUR** code and the issues/errors with your code) and why this is different to the previous question (and why the solution is not just to use the same answer from the previous question and use `UNION ALL` to combine tables 2 and 3).

Comment: As I said, use `UNION ALL` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DRpKykMc)

Comment: Note: commentary on duplicates should go at the end of a question, so that new readers can see the context before trying to understand the meta-commentary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is effectively the same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77275236/); however you just need to use `UNION ALL` to concatenate the tables:

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       t2.date_column,
       CASE
       WHEN t2.date_column >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '10' DAY
       THEN 'pass'
       ELSE 'fail'
       END AS result
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT id,
                date_column,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY id, TRUNC(date_column, 'MM')
                  ORDER BY date_column DESC
                ) AS rn
         FROM   (
           SELECT *
           FROM   table2
         UNION ALL
           SELECT *
           FROM   table3
         )
       ) t2
       ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t2.rn = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (id) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (id, date_column) AS
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) -  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 52 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table3 (id, date_column) AS
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) -  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 18 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | DATE_COLUMN | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-04 00:00:00 | pass |
| 2 | 2023-10-03 00:00:00 | pass |
| 3 | 2023-08-22 00:00:00 | fail |
| 3 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | fail |

If you want, you can reduce the rows being concatenated by pre-filtering the tables (you will need to test how that affects performance as it may help or it may prevent the SQL engine from applying a optimisation and may reduce performance; we do not have your tables/indexes/data so cannot test):

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       t2.date_column,
       CASE
       WHEN t2.date_column >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '10' DAY
       THEN 'pass'
       ELSE 'fail'
       END AS result
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT id,
                date_column,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY id, TRUNC(date_column, 'MM')
                  ORDER BY date_column DESC
                ) AS union_rn
         FROM   (
           SELECT id, date_column
           FROM   (
             SELECT id,
                    date_column,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                      PARTITION BY id, TRUNC(date_column, 'MM')
                      ORDER BY date_column DESC
                    ) AS rn
             FROM   table2
           )
           WHERE rn = 1
         UNION ALL
           SELECT id, date_column
           FROM   (
             SELECT id,
                    date_column,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                      PARTITION BY id, TRUNC(date_column, 'MM')
                      ORDER BY date_column DESC
                    ) AS rn
             FROM   table3
           )
           WHERE rn = 1
         )
       ) t2
       ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t2.union_rn = 1)
```

Which gives the same output.

Other than using `ROW_NUMBER`, you could also find the values using:

- `MAX(date_column)` and `GROUP BY id, TRUNC(date_column, 'MM')`; or
- possibly `LATERAL` join from the `id` values and use `FETCH FIRST ROW [ONLY|WITH TIES]` to get the latest date (but that might not be so easy to get each month).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AUJ_OnaF)

Comment: Really appreciate @MT0, the solution & the way it easily explained, thank you so much, there is an extension of this question with a difference I've posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77285414/monthly-entry-tracking, if you could please look into it, thank you