# Monthly entry tracking

Tags: sql, oracle

Here the aim is to create the output table based on 3 input table,
logic is to fetch the last record for each month for each id which gives the id & date (date column is to be extracted from table 2 and not table 3) respectively, since id 2 does not have last day of month which is 30th June, I pick the last day available in the given data.

This question is similar to an old question, so I'm mentioning here the difference between the two questions: 'result' column is framed as 'pass' if an 'id' has a date entry at least once in the past 30 days from that date (and not from current sysdate) either in table 2 or in table 3, else the result of the student is fail.

Input:

table1

| id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | stud |
| 2 | stud |
| 3 | stud |

table2

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-09-2023 |
| 1 | 29-09-2023 |
| 2 | 25-06-2023 |
| 3 | 15-08-2023 |

table3:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-09-2023 |
| 1 | 29-09-2023 |
| 1 | 29-08-2023 |
| 2 | 29-05-2023 |
| 3 | 17-07-2023 |

Output

| id | date | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-09-2023 | pass |
| 1 | 29-08-2023 | fail |
| 2 | 29-06-2023 | pass |
| 2 | 29-05-2023 | fail |
| 3 | 15-08-2023 | pass |
| 3 | 17-07-2023 | fail |

Explanation of result column in output:

id 1 for September is 'pass' since it has a date entry in either table 2 or table 3 in past 30 days from 30th Sep
id 1 for August is 'fail' because it does not have a date entry in past 30 days from 29th Aug across both table 1 & 2
id 2 for June is 'pass' because it has a date entry in past 30 days from table 3, while id 2 for May is 'fail', and so on

Comment: Please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Comment: Also please read your question again assuming you are someone who see this entire text **for the first time** and knows nothing about your tables, columns, data and calculation rules and try to answer it. It's completely unclear how, for example, `category` is relevant for the output (also it seems to be a poor sample data because it is the same value for all rows), or what is the difference between `table2` and `table3` - their names are meaningless, their structures are the same.

Comment: Can you also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: In the section that references the possible duplicate, could you add a link to it? (Please do not try to declare that a question is definitively not a duplicate - readers can be the judge of that. You might have missed one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is effectively the same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77281186/conditional-pass-fail-column-sql?noredirect=1&lq=1) but using the `LAG`/`LEAD` analytic functions to find the previous date rather than using `SYSDATE`:

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       t2.date_column,
       CASE
       WHEN t2.date_column <= prev_date + INTERVAL '30' DAY
       THEN 'pass'
       ELSE 'fail'
       END AS result
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT id,
                date_column,
                LEAD(date_column) OVER (
                  PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_column DESC
                ) As prev_date,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY id, TRUNC(date_column, 'MM')
                  ORDER BY date_column DESC
                ) AS rn
         FROM   (
           SELECT *
           FROM   table2
         UNION ALL
           SELECT *
           FROM   table3
         )
       ) t2
       ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t2.rn = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (id) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (id, date_column) AS
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) -  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 52 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table3 (id, date_column) AS
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) -  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 18 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | DATE_COLUMN | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-04 00:00:00 | pass |
| 2 | 2023-10-03 00:00:00 | pass |
| 3 | 2023-08-22 00:00:00 | fail |
| 3 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 | pass |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_8Rbv9kr)